# Import Excel Workbooks from Sharepoint List

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have a series of Excel workbooks that are uploaded as Attachments to items on a List on my team's SharePoint site.  I'm trying to find a way to import the data from all of these workbooks into one master Excel Workbook so I can aggregate the data and conduct analysis.

So far, I've been able to import the list itself into the workbook, but not the actual .xlsx files attached to the items in the list that house the data I'm looking to analyze.

Is this possible to do in Excel 2016?

Thanks for any help you can provide,

- CS